# What in this code causes memory leak in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

In the Windows Task Manager I discovered that memory usage of my program is increases over time while it's running. The memory leak is caused by the code below. The code is a loop iterating over a list of images and resizes them according to code example in MSDN. All resources seem to be managed and are freed with .Dispose().

```
foreach ( string file in files )
{
    image = Image.FromFile( file );

    Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 );
    Bitmap src = ( Bitmap ) image;
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap( cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height );

    using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( target ) )  
    {
        g.DrawImage( src, new Rectangle( 0, 0, target.Width, target.Height ),
                                        cropRect,
                                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
    }

    image.Dispose();
    image = Image.FromHbitmap( target.GetHbitmap() );
    src.Dispose();
    target.Dispose();
    image.Dispose();
}
```

Could someone advise please what can be the cause of the memory leak in this code?

Comment: This is not so much an answer to the question (which Lucas seems to have nailed), but to follow up on his deleted comment: How do you know resources are leaking (could you add that to your post) and also, a preferred method for Graphics and things are to use 'using' blocks: using(Graphics g)
{
    // do something with the resource
}  -- This will automatically call dispose when going out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Will add this to the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs of `GetHbitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx):

> You are responsible for calling the GDI `DeleteObject` method to free the memory used by the GDI bitmap object. For more information about GDI bitmaps, see Bitmaps in the Windows GDI documentation.

Then, from the [docs of `FromHbitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x.aspx):

> The `FromHbitmap` method makes a copy of the GDI bitmap; so you can release the incoming GDI bitmap using the GDI `DeleteObject` method immediately after creating the new Image.

Seems pretty clear... You need to call `DeleteObject`:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

As SJoshi points out, you should use `using` blocks to ensure `Dispose` is called in case of exception. The `DeleteObject` call should be inside a `finally` block to get the same effect.

Comment: If you use the using blocks do you still need to call DeleteObject?

Comment: @jfin3204 yes, because `Image.FromHbitmap` makes a copy of the image and doesn't free the handle you pass it. You have to free it manually.